# Lookup, Find, Match and Replace Cells in Excel, Help or Advise Needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question I am hoping someone can assist with an answer if it's possible to do in excel.

I have two spreadsheets (SS). Both SS has over 500 lines of products, with two columns of particular interest I need help with. Both SS has almost all the same products, except one has more than the other.

Let's call one SS 'Old' and the other 'New' - Old has fewer products than the New.

I need to replace the 'New' with 'Old' product "handle ID's". These "Handle ID's" Need to match the "SKU ID's". It's the SKU's that will be the main identifying number to match the matching connection.

So if SKU = 123456 in the 'Old' and has a "Handle ID" of "BIC Orange Pen 3mm". I want that handle to change in the 'New' SS. I need to match OLD SKU: 123456 to NEW SKU to update/change the NEW Handle that currently says "Pen, 3mm Orange, BIC" to "BIC Orange Pen 3mm"

Does this make sense?

I would totally love to be able to do it all in a moments click instead of changing one 'Handle ID" at a time.

Can this be achieved or am I dreaming?

Thanks in advance.

(I don't sell BIC pens, I was just using an example)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more examples of data of old versus new? Is all data structured as: `<product_type (various string length)>` `<separator:", ">` `<size (various string length)>` `<separator:" ">` `<colour (various string length)>` `<separator: ", ">` `<brand name (various string length)>`

Comment: I have added an image - Thanks

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you're trying to get as a result. Are you trying to 1) check if a different new handle exists for the old and return the new value if true and return the old value if false? Or are you trying to 2) lookup if it exists or not and if true return the new value, if false mix the value so it is arranged the same way as other new handles? Both are possible. 1) is a simple lookup or index match. 2) is a combination of lookup or index match and xmlfilter and wouldn't be as simple as 1)

Comment: Yes, you understand. 1) check if a different new handle exists for the old and return the new value if true and return the old value if false. 

I do apologise for my explanations, I am not really great at it. You managed to work it out!

Comment: So how do that? lol

Comment: For given example paste the following formula in a cell in row 2 and copy down. `=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$4, MATCH(B2,$E$2:$E$4,0)),A2)`. Note that your given data doesn't show examples of old ID's that don't have a new ID.

Answer (score 0):

If the SKU in both the old and new sheets are the same, why not just use a simple `VLOOKUP`?

If the data runs from A1:B100 in both sheets, something like this should do the trick:

`=VLOOKUP(A1, Old_SS_Range, 2, 0)`